# Downgrade framework made controls databinding fail on winforms (xp)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, frameworks

I wrote a WinForms application based on .Net 4.5, in VisualStudio 2013. Some forms are written with a mvvm pattern:

- View (a form with controls, designer and an empty cs file)
- A partial class with the same name of the form
- A class that is the ViewModel.

The controls are bound to the viewmodel in this way:

```
controlName.DataBindigs.Add("controlProperty", model_instance, property_inside_model, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Even some user control are bound to the model properties in the same way.

All worked fine in the 4.5 version, but they asked me to downgrade to the 4.0 version of the FrameWork, because many users have still XP. Once downgraded the application to the  4.0 framework, everything worked nice in the developer machine (Windiows 7 64bit). But publishing it on the target machine, a 32 bit virtual XP, the above databinding don't works anymore.

Installing VS 2010 on the virtual XP, the debugger always complains:
"Cannot bind to the property or column 'propertyname' on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember".

This happens with all the user controls, and with some property of windows controls, expecially with the SelectedValue Property of comboboxes.

What happens? Is the .net Framework 4.0 of Vs 2013 different from thye one installed on XP?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The behaviour described above is triggered only when i try to bind to a control to a property of an object inside the model, and not a property OF the model. The properties like `model.Name` etc, works good, but those like `model.Customer.Name` do not. I fixed the problem assigning, as datasource for the binding, a wrapper of the model, a BindingSource:

instead of this:

```
control.DataBindings.Add(control_property, model, "ObjectInstance.Property"`, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

i wrote this:

```
Bindingsource bs = new BindingSource(model, null);

control.DataBindings.Add(control_property, bs, "ObjectInstance.Property", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

and it worked.

Hope this could help someone with the same problems.

But, as there are still some errors of a different kind compared with the no-errors version in vs2013-windows7, with THE SAME net Framework, i would like to know if someone has the same problems with an application running nice on seven and with errors on xp.

Thanks to all